# how to delete the same elements in an array except one of them

Tags: java, arrays

how can get rid of unnecessary elements of an arrayList?

example

```
input:["a","b","c","d",c","e","a"]
output:["a","b","c","d","e"]
```

i wrote this algorithm but it doesn't work. **i dont get an error message** however i cannot ged rid of the unnecessary ones.

java

```
for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++){

            for (int y=i+1;y<array.size();y++){

                if (array.get(i).equals(array.get(y))){
                    array.remove(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
```

Comment: What kind of object is `array`? Looks like an `ArrayList`? *it doesn't work* is not an error description. What is the problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use Set instead of Arrays because Set is a collection of objects in which duplicate values cannot be stored.

Or you can transform your array into a set like this :

```
        Set<String> setWithoutDuplicate = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

This way all duplicated and unnecessary values will be removed.